# Unity - Using RayCast to orient object to terrain (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a flight simulator. Right now, I am trying to get the plane to fly on its own, but I am having some problems with trying to rotate the plane such that it is parallel to the ground.

This is my code:

```
heightDetect = new Ray (transform.position, Vector3.down);

        if (Physics.Raycast (heightDetect, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
            Debug.Log (hit.distance);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;


            Debug.DrawRay (heightDetect.origin, heightDetect.direction*1000);

        }
```

The code works and all, but the problem is it is way too bumpy. The camera on the plane keeps jerking about on my screen, and is completely unplayable. Is there a way to smoothen this process? Thank you!

Comment: I tried this before and it was very hard to get a smooth movement. The further away the object is from the ground the harder it gets! The problem happens on the next frame after you align your plain to the normal, because then your raycast is going to hit a different normal an will thus get a different rotation. You absolutely must find a suitable (L)erping method and smoothly rotate towards the normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are doing this in your `Update` function, and therefore changing the rotation of your plane many times per second. Instead of directly setting the rotation, you could use [spherical linear interpolation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html):

```
public float speed = 0.1f;

void Update() {
    ...
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

This effectively smoothes the rotation over time. It works by taking the current rotation and the eventual desired rotation, but only returning a rotation somewhere in between (controlled by `speed`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the [Quaternion.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) to smooth your rotation for Quaternions, or [Mathf.LerpAngle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpAngle.html) for Vector3 rotation.

Usage example:

```
Vector3 currentRotation = transform.rotation;
Vector3 newRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
newRotation = new Vector3(
                 Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotation.x, newRotation.x, Time.deltaTime),
                 Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotation.y, newRotation.y, Time.deltaTime),
                 Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotation.z, newRotation.z, Time.deltaTime));
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Multiply `Time.deltaTime` by any value to change lerp's "speed".

Comment: I find that the "speed" you mention is dependent on the distance to the hitpoint. Maybe the speed should be calculated...

Comment: "Speed" in terms of Lerp function controls how fast original value will "become" target value. Its just how fast you want it to be. For example Lerp(1, 2, 0.5f) where 0.5f is our "speed"-value, will result int 1.5f. And Lerp(1, 2, 0.75f) will result in 1.75f. So in second example with higher "speed", the result of the function will be bigger.

Comment: Yea sure, I know how to use Lerping methods. I am just saying that the further you are away from the ground the slower you should rotate or the object starts to become jumpy again. This is why it worked very well for me to calculate the "speed" based on the distance to the ground.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yeah, probably thats a good idea. I just not familiar with this kind of games, but I understood your point.